# My pygame window says "not responding" when I use collidepoint()

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game. In my game there is a shop and a fight mode. When I use `collidepoint()`, and if `collidepoint()` is `True`, then it calls a function. But when I call the function the window says, **not reponding**. I can't figure out this problem, I hope you can fix it.

```
def lvl1():
    screen.blit(stickmanlvlim,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
def lvl2():
    screen.blit(stickmanlvlim,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
def lvl3():
    screen.blit(stickmanlvlim,(0,0))
    pygame.display.update()
        


def fight(events):
    lvl1R = pygame.Rect((20,335),(50,50))
    lvl2R = pygame.Rect((170,335),(50,50))
    lvl3R = pygame.Rect((320,335),(50,50))
    world1setup()
    fight = True
    while fight:
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                fight = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                spot2 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if lvl1R.collidepoint(spot2):
                    lvl1()
                if lvl2R.collidepoint(spot2):
                    lvl2()
                if lvl3R.collidepoint(spot2):
                    lvl3()
```

The problem is in the `fight()` function. There is no error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  It would be easier for someone to help you if they had to look at less code.  You need to remove lines of code that aren't related to the question so others can focus on the important part.

Comment: Sounds good!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the event in different function for example:

```
def fight(events):
  lvl1R = pygame.Rect((20,335),(50,50))
  lvl2R = pygame.Rect((170,335),(50,50))
  lvl3R = pygame.Rect((320,335),(50,50))
  world1setup()
  fight = True
  while fight:
    spot2 = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if lvl1R.collidepoint(spot2):
       lvl1()
    if lvl2R.collidepoint(spot2):
       lvl2()
    if lvl3R.collidepoint(spot2):
       lvl3()
def main():
   run = True
   while run:
      events = pygame.event.get()
      for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            fight(events)
main()
```

don't forget to add the `pygame.event.get()` at the beginning of the while loop.

Comment: that didn't work, it still gets stuck. I don't sundertsnad why it keeps getting stuck..

Comment: Try calling '''pygame.event.get()''' at the beginning of the while loop.